# I have set setCancelable(false), but the Dialog can't work as modal window

Tags: android

I have set setCancelable(false). In my mind, the code will display a Dialog windows first, and the Dialog windows will close after I click OK button.

but in fact, the code close whole app directly without displaying Dialog windows.

How can I display Dialog before close whole app?

```
   findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(SMSMain.this);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.DeleteInContextPrompt));
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.Warning));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //I won't add finish() here
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();

        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        AlertDialog dialog;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(SMSMain.this);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.DeleteInContextPrompt));
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.Warning));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.dismiss(); 
                  finish();// call finish() to close this activity for OK click  
            }
        });

        dialog=builder.create();
        dialog.show();

       // finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How can I display Dialog before close whole app.
try

```
public void onStop(){
super.onStop();

 findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(SMSMain.this);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.DeleteInContextPrompt));
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.Warning));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //I won't add finish() here
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();


    }
});  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because of  `finish();` you activity destroy.
use `dialog.dismis();` to dismiss your dialog

Answer (score 0):

// finish(); this which you have written in your code inside OnClick is the issue, its making your whole app to close even before dialog, if you want o close your app after user clicks Okay in your dialog, call finish() inside click event of your posivtive button.

Also make sure to override onBackPressed, in case you want to pop a dialog when user presess back button to close your actvity.